# Extract documentation from an r package

Tags: r, documentation

I'm trying to write an R function which will extract exported functions from an R package and return a list containing for each function, the call signature, and the description from documentation.

Getting the list of exported functions can be done with relative ease by doing the following:

```
# Extracts all exported function names from dplyr
library(dplyr) 
lsf.str("package:dplyr")
```

I can also get the call signature for a given function using the name:

```
# Extract call signature for the join function in dplyr
lsf.str("package:dplyr")[10] %>%
  get() %>%
  deparse() %>%
  head(1)
```

I can even automatically open up the help section for each one of those functions:

```
# Opens help for the join function in dplyr
help(lsf.str("package:dplyr")[10], package = "dplyr")
```

But how can can I return a string containing the text of the description for this function?  So, for the join function in dplyr, it ought to return:

> These are generic functions that dispatch to individual tbl methods - see the method documentation for details of individual data sources. x and y should usually be from the same data source, but if copy is TRUE, y will automatically be copied to the same source as x.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

```
library(tidyverse)

lsf.str("package:dplyr")[10] %>% 
  help("dplyr") %>%
  utils:::.getHelpFile() %>% 
  keep(~attr(.x, "Rd_tag") == "\\description") %>% 
  map(as.character) %>% 
  flatten_chr() %>% 
  paste0(., collapse="")
## [1] "\nThese are generic functions that dispatch to individual tbl methods - see the\nmethod documentation for details of individual data sources. x and\ny should usually be from the same data source, but if copy is\nTRUE, y will automatically be copied to the same source as x.\n"
```

Removing newlines is an exercise left to the OP :-)

Comment: This works very well most of the time, but sometimes results in formatting code mixed in.  For example, pulling usage from mean results in:  "\nmean(x, list())\n\nlist(list(\"mean\"), list(\"default\"))(x, trim = 0, na.rm = FALSE, list())\n"
Is there a way to get clear out these list calls?

Comment: Yes. This is called "working". You have an outline for a generic solution that works for most cases. There are plenty of hints in the existing code for where to look for more answers. Perfection is up to the seeker or others who want to do your work for you.

Comment: Please don't take my follow-up as me not working, as that would be an entirely false assumption. I am working on this and many other things.  If you or anyone else has an answer to my follow-up and care to offer it, I will greatly appreciate it.  I further appreciate the answer you've already given, which is very useful.